# Can I get results from a Postgres query that I got disconnected from?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I started an hours-long Postgres query in my `psql` shell. Then, I got disconnected from the network and had to make a new `psql` shell. If I look in `pg_stat_activity`, I see that my query is still running. Can I connect to that query and get its output?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. However, if the query is for changing data and there isn't any transaction started, then it will make the change. Next time start a [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [save results to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331320/psql-save-results-of-command-to-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

No. If the process is long use intermediate tables + screen.